# how to get count of ratings in the past 24hrs using django datetime?

Tags: datetime, django-models

I have a model name Ratings where there is a timestamp. I want to limit the user to only 3 ratings per day. **how do I get a count of ratings for a particular user the past 24hrs?**

```
class Ratings(models.Model):   
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    book = models.ForeignKey('Books')
    rating = models.IntegerField(max_length=150)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_checkedin_rating = models.BooleanField()
```

edit* 
To be more clear, I want to find the count of ratings by a particular user in 24hrs. So from let's say 5/13 12AM to 5/14 12AM, get the count of ratings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
end_time = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(today.toordinal()) // today at 12:00am or 00:00
start_time = end_time -  datetime.timedelta(days=1) yesterday at 12:00am

count = Ratings.objects.filter(
    user=some_user,
    timestamp__gte=start_time,
    timestamp__lte=end_time
).count()
```

Comment: isnt timestamp=datetime.date.today() just finding the ratings with timestamp that is today()?

Comment: Yes, it finding the ratings with timestamp for today for a particular user and returning the count. For example user has 2 ratings for today. Is that what you want?

Comment: I think I didn't explain well, I want to get the count of the ratings in one days time. So from 5/13 12am to 5/14 12am, I would get the count of ratings the user did. Thanks for your help!